# Variable assigned in an else block leads to "variable not used" compilation error

Tags: go

here's the code: https://play.golang.org/p/H5x2lgGpbRL

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x bool
    m := map[int]bool{1: false}

    if 1 == 2 {
        x = true
    } else {
        x, ok := m[1]
        if !ok {
            fmt.Printf("error")
            return
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%t", x)
}
```

leads to `./prog.go:14:3: x declared but not used`

I would expect this to compile, because x is used in the last line.

Could someone please explain the scoping rules here?

Comment: The error is for `x` at line 14. This is a new variable that is indeed not used. The `x, ok := m[1]` line creates a new variable `x` that shadows the `x` from line 8. This new `x` is only valid in the `else` block and is never used there.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `:=` operator, which introduces two new variables in line 14: `x` and `ok`. `x` shadows the `x` declared in line 8.

To get around this you have to use `=` instead of `:=`. For that to work you must pre-declare `ok` right before assigning it like so:

```
...
var ok bool
x, ok = m[1]
...
```